# Apache mod_rewrite for different folders

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I need my page to have a two-tier redirect via htaccess.
First, I have clean-URL functionality for the "base" page, specifically redirecting about ANY URL to a single front controller script "main.php".

Here, anything after the "base domain" is to be passed as a variable to the main script, which can then act on it.

For example, `domain.com/a/b` will redirect to something like `domain.com/main.php$param=a/b`

This is working just fine with the following .htaccess code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ main.php?param=$1

</IfModule>
```

Now the part where I am lost: I want to have one ACTUAL folder with a different script/functionality/layout etc. This script MUST NOT be accessed via the main.php script from above. For the sake of this example, let's call this folder `test-folder`.

The behavior I want/need is that all URLs with `test` after the domain-part get forwarded to a different script in the same manner. In total:

`domain.com` => `domain.com/main.php`

and

`domain.com/a/b` => `domain.com/main.php?param=a/b`

BUT

`domain.com/test` => `domain.com/test-folder/test.php`

and subsequently

`domain.com/test/a/b` => `domain.com/test-folder/test.php?param=a/b`

Now I tried different combinations of rewrite rules, such as

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^test/(.*)$ test-folder/test.php?param=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ main.php?param=$1 [L,NC]
```

This gives me a scenario, where everything is redirected to the base URL's main.php script, no parameters work. Worthless. Next, I tried:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^test/(.*)$ test-folder/test.php?param=$1 [L,NC]
```

This works perfectly for the test-folder, but not for the main folder (duh!). So I tried:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ main.php?param=$1 [L,NC]
```

This lets all requests to the base domain work perfectly, but all requests to test get redirected to the main-script as well. Duh again. Still, both rules individually work just as intended.

How do I get both rules to work IN COMBINATION?

Thanks in advance!

PS: Here's an example with what should be matched how:

```
domain.com/ => domain.com/main.php?param=
domain.com/a => domain.com/main.php?param=a
domain.com/a/b/c/more => domain.com/main.php?param=a/b/c/more
domain.com/test/ => domain.com/test/test.php?param=
domain.com/test/a => domain.com/test/test.php?param=a
domain.com/test/a/b/c/more => domain.com/test/test.php?param=a/b/c/more
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I found the answer after several hours myself.

```
RewriteRule ^test(.*)$ test-folder/test.php?param=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ main.php?param=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```